# How to set job artifacts with tags to never expire Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, artifacts

I am wondering is there any possibility to set job that generate artifacts to never expire if the commit is with a tag else it should expire. Currently, it is globally set to expire after 3 days. But I want something like if a commit is done with a specific `tag` and it runs a `Job A` which generates artifacts then it should never expire. But the same `Job A` should run for other commits without tags and the artifacts generated for that should expire within the globally set time.

Answer (score 7):

See [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#configure-a-job-artifact-to-never-expire) (August 2020), this is officially supported
(as opposed to a "workaround", with `expire_in 5 years`!)

> ### Configure a job artifact to never expire
>
> As a developer, you have the ability to specify a job artifact’s exact expiration date, but there are scenarios where you may need to retain an artifact forever.
>
> Now, you can set an artifact to never expire by setting the value of `expire_in` to `never` in your CI configuration.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactsexpire_in) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22761).

---

The OP clarifies:

> I have one job which runs for every commit and the artifacts for this jobs expires in three days but for the same job if there is a commit with tag I want the artifacts to be kept forever.

---

Note: [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#lock-the-latest-job-artifact-to-prevent-deletion) (September 2020) adds an interesting feature:

> ### Lock the latest job artifact to prevent deletion
>
> GitLab will now automatically lock the latest artifact of a successful job and pipeline on any active branch, MR, or tag to prevent it from being deleted based on expiration. This makes it easier to set a more aggressive expiration policy to clean up older artifacts, helps reduce disk space consumption, and ensures you’ve always got a copy of the latest artifact from your pipeline.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactsexpire_in) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/16267).

Answer (score 7):

You could have a dedicated job to handle artifact persistence that runs on tag only. Something like:

```
persist-tag-artifacts:
  # Use this job to specify artifacts that should never expire for tag pipelines.
  stage: post-deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null'
  script:
    - echo "Persisting artifacts for tag pipelines"
  artifacts:
    # Specify artifacts from previous jobs to be persisted indefinitely
    paths:
      - myArtifactsPathFromJob1
      - myArtifactsPathFromJob2
      - ...
    expire_in: never
```

Run this job after the last "artifact-creating" stage of your pipeline. All the artifacts from jobs of previous stages are automatically copied to this job. If you don't want all artifacts to be copied but only the ones you'd like to persist you can use the `dependencies` keyword.

It would still be nicer though if Gitlab had a way to conditionally set a global "expire_in: never"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [artifact expiry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in) per job.

So for the job where it's using the particular tag, then you'd set the artifact to expire in some long period of time

```
job:
  tags:
    - your_tag
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 5 yr
```

Comment: It is correct for jobs that run for specific tags. But I think my question is not correctly written I will edit it. I have one job which runs for every commit and the artifacts for this jobs expires in three days but for the same job if there is a commit with ```tag``` I want the artifacts to be kept forever.